# How to use chan postevent in reflected channel in Tcl

Tags: tcl

I am trying to implement a simple non blocking reflected channel in TCL which calls C APIs when reading and writing. I have followed the [Example](https://wiki.tcl-lang.org/page/reflected+channel) in Tcl wiki:

```
package provide rchan 1.0

namespace eval  rchan {

variable chan        ;# set of known channels (for my implememtation 

proc initialize {chanid args} {

    #This is implemented in C (All the init, data and handles are processed in C)
    ClientOpen

    set map [dict create]
    dict set map finalize    [list ::rchan::finalize $chanid]
    dict set map watch       [list ::rchan::watch $chanid]
    dict set map write       [list ::rchan::write $chanid]
    dict set map read        [list ::rchan::read $chanid]

    namespace ensemble create -map $map -command ::$chanid

    return "initialize finalize watch read write"
}

proc finalize {chanid} {
    variable chan
    unset chan
    #This function is implemented in C
    ClientClose
}

variable watching
array set watching {read 0 write 0}

proc watch {chanid events} {
    variable watching
    # Channel no longer interested in events that are not in $events
    foreach event {read write} {
        set watching($event) 0
    }
    foreach event $events {
        set watching($event) 1
    }
}

proc read {chanid count} {
    #ClientRead is a non blocking call in C API
    set result [ClientRead]
    return $result
}

proc write {chanid data} {
    #ClientWrite is implemented in C API, makes sure all the data is written.
    set dsize [ClientWrite $data]
    return $dsize        ;# number of bytes actually written
}

namespace export -clear *
namespace ensemble create -subcommands {}
}
```

I am not knowing where to implement the event notification mechanism, I have read the **generic/tclIORChan.c** file which has implementation of reflected channel, from what I understand, watch proc tells the notifier which events we are interested, this is done when we call:

> chan event channelId event ?script?

So if we execute:

> chan event $channel readable ?some script?

It calls the watch proc and sets the read=1 in watch array and with writable write=1.

and *chan postevent* is used to actually trigger the event.

I have C API ClientReadReady which is non blocking and returns 1 when client sends some data and we can read it ( This contains something like checking FD_ISSET and returning a value). I am not understanding where to put this to trigger the event, something like

```
if {[ClientReadReady] == 1} {
    chan postevent $chanid read
}
```

Do I need to implement some kind of timer with after command to poll the status of "ClientReadReady" and post the event when it is ready?

Comment: There is an underlying file descriptor that knows this? Why not use that (plus the Tcl notifier) to tell you when to think about posting the event?

Comment: @DonalFellows yes the client API's have descriptors which have this information they can be polled to know when data is available. Can you please provide some link where I can know how to use the Tcl notifier?

Answer (score 0):

I have the equivalent of the following in my write procedure:

```
variable watching
if { $watching(read) } {
  chan postevent $chanid read
}
```

and the wiki example has something similar.

Comment: When we do `chan event $channel readable ?some script?` doesn't $watching(read) always evaluate to true since we are assigning $watching(read) to 1 in watch proc? I want to read only when there is data ready in the channel, which can be checked by calling `ClientReadReady` proc.

Comment: If something was just written, then there is data ready to be read.

Comment: Yes, but we don't know if something was written, if the underlying client is Socket client we don't know when the data is written. We have to poll status of `ClientReadReady` proc to know if something was written.

Comment: If the `write` procedure gets called by the reflected channel infrastructure, then something was written.

Comment: I think you are thinking of some kind of "echo" channel where we write and read form the same buffer. The channel I have implemented is like socket channel where client gets data from the server and writes data to the server with write procedure, we don't know when the server may send data to the client so client needs to poll the status of the available data to know when the data is available in buffer to read.